# Codimensions of $\mathbb{Q}$-subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, axiom-of-choice

Under the Axiom of Choice, we can pick a Hamel basis $H$ for $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Adjoining all but some elements of $H$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ shows that for any cardinality $1\leq\kappa\leq c$ there is an intermediate field $\mathbb{R}-F-\mathbb{Q}$ such that the extension $\mathbb{R}:F$ has degree $\kappa$.

Can some part of this result (especially when $\kappa <c$) be obtained without AC?

Comment: Except for countable k, probably not. Without AC , I don't know whether it can be shown that R has a Hamel basis over Q. It is also consistent with ZF that there is a vector space V with 2 cardinally incomparable Hamel bases. I don't know whether V can be R or some subspace of R. Also, a vector subspace of R must have a countably infinite subspace and it is consistent with ZF that there is a Tarski-infinite, Dedekind-finite set S. I don't know whether S can be a subset of R,but if so, there could be further difficulties.